# Using Dependency Injection with Http Handlers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, httphandler, ninject

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 with Ninject, and Linq2SQL behind a repository pattern, based on [Rob Conery's TekPub Starter Site](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/05/24/mvc-starter-2).

With controllers it all works fine, however I have an HTTP Handler (it serves and resizes images from a DB), and I have no idea how I use Ninject to replace my ISession interface with a concrete instance of my LinqToSQLSession.

How should I best do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use property injection. I have used it with StructureMap, but Ninject should support it

Define a base class for your http handlers, and hook DI in there.

**Update:**

Check here for what's property injection vs. other types of injection: http://wiki.github.com/ninject/ninject/injection-patterns

In the base class for the handlers you need to get a hold of your ninject IKernel instance and call .Inject(this) on initialization.

Comment: Is there any more detail you could give, I'm at a loss where to start.

Answer (score 1):

This SO question is about using ninject w/ HttpHandlers:  [HttpHandler Property Injection using Ninject returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629472/httphandler-property-injection-using-ninject-returning-null)

Wish I could give you a better answer, but hopefully that will be enough to get you going.  Good luck!

Comment: +1 the linked answer its not exactly property injection,  but using service locator would be another approach. I still prefer the earlier.