# IHttphandler Property Injection In MVC2 Using Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm looking for a way to do property injection in MVC for IHttpHandlers.

In the case of webforms ninject you could just inherit from HttpHandlerBase.

This no longer works as the application now inherits from Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectApplication NOT Ninject.Web.NinjectHttpApplication.

This application registers types for controllers not PageBase, MasterPageBase or HttpHandlerBase.

Rubbish.

Is their a way of doing it maybe with the MvcHandler class?

The post below is the closest I've come to an answer.

[HttpHandler Property Injection using Ninject returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629472/httphandler-property-injection-using-ninject-returning-null)

Comment: Why are you using HttpHandlers with MVC?  I'd think you'd replace them with a suitable controller/action.

Comment: Only just starting out with MVC, had a feeling their would be more MVC way of doing it. My concern would be if I would need to update all controllers which used the handler (or in a controller base class?). It does not seem as clean as registering a handler in the web.config. Could I do this in a controller if the handler was in a class library? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build Ninject.Web.Mvc from source, include a copy of the HttpHandlerBase class from Ninject.Web in the Ninject.Web.Mvc namespace.

Otherwise your own HttpHandlerBase will need to call `Kernel.Inject` on itself. The kernel reference can be obtained via Application scope, or via reflection.

In `HttpApplication.CreateKernel()` store the kernel instance in the Application scope as "NinjectKernel". Then add the following as your IHttpHandler base class.

```
public abstract class HttpHandlerBase : IHttpHandler
{
    public abstract void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context );

    void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest( HttpContext context )
    {
        var kernel = (IKernel) context.Application["NinjectKernel"];
        kernel.Inject( this );

        this.ProcessRequest( context );
    }
}
```

The reflection approach does not require any code in your HttpApplication.

```
public abstract class HttpHandlerBase : IHttpHandler
{
    public abstract void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context );

    void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest( HttpContext context )
    {
        Assembly ass = Assembly.Load("Ninject.Web.Mvc");
        Type type = ass.GetType("Ninject.Web.Mvc.KernelContainer");
        MethodInfo init = type.GetMethod("Inject", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { typeof(object) }, null );
        init.Invoke( null, new object[] {} );

        this.ProcessRequest( context );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate that perfect. Any idea why the Ninject team have removed the HttpHandlerBase from the MVC version?

Adapting and rebuilding source code never feels ideal as you can always inject bugs into the system and you need to track all your changes and apply them all again when you update to a new version. Yes, I am a lazy programmer, but in a good way I hope lol!

If any of the Ninject team are reading this, why has this feature been removed for MVC and are their any reasons why you wouldn't add it to a future version?


Cheers again for the answer. 

Steve